# Do MIT students omit square braces of SI unit?

Tags: conventions, notation, units, si-units

$$  v:=\text{symbol which represents a speed }  $$

As concrete value of $ v$ is specified, at least the below 2 notations can be done.

$$  \text{notation 1} \rightarrow   v=10 \left[ \frac{  \text{m}   }{  \text{s} ^{}   }  \right]  $$

$$  \text{notation 2} \rightarrow   v=10 ~~  \frac{  \text{m}   }{  \text{s} ^{}   }    $$

As specific value of $v$ is undefined, at least the below 2 notations can be done.

$$  \text{notation 3}  \rightarrow v \left[ \frac{  \text{m}   }{  \text{s} ^{}   }  \right]  $$

$$  \text{notation 4}  \rightarrow v  ~~   \frac{  \text{m}   }{  \text{s} ^{}   }    $$

I know each of the notations is correct but I've been wondering how students of MIT or other high level schools write of it.

Of course I can guess that in a  process of calculation, square braces of si unit are used in tests or assignments of MIT.

I may specifically want to know whether  square braces are ommited in last descriptions in answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DanielC is correct, and I will spell out the logic a bit more.

1. Numbers are dimensionless. e.g. $1$, $2$, $-5.3$, $\pi$, etc. They can be used without further comment to indicate the size of things which are also dimensionless, such as the number of coins in a bag, or the value of a phase, or something like that.
2. Physical quantities such as length, time and mass are dimensional.
3. Units such as metre, second, kilogram are also dimensional; they refer to some agreed amount of the relevant physical quantity.
4. Symbols in physics, such as $x$, $t$, $m$, $v$, $a$, etc. ordinarily mean "the physical quantity" not "the size of the physical quantity divided by some unit".

With the above in mind, the following equations make sense:
$$
x = 1.3\,\mbox{meters} \\
m = 5\,{\rm kg}
$$
The first equation says "take a metre, multiply it by $1.3$, and you have $x$". The second equation says "take a kilogram, multiply it by $5$, and you have $m$."

If we are logical, therefore, then if $x$ is a length (as specified above) then the quantity "$x\,$metres" means "($1.3\,$metres metres)" which is $1.3\,{\rm m}^2$, i.e. an area. This way of writing such a result is utterly misleading. *Therefore do not ever write or think "$x$ metres" if in fact $x$ is itself a distance*. You will only confuse yourself or others.

Similarly, do not write "$v$ m/s" if $v$ is itself a speed.

You can if you like write $n$ m/s if $n$ is a dimensionless number and you wish to discuss a speed whose size is $n$ m/s. But is this $n$ itself a speed? No it is not. It is a number.

The practice of writing "$v$ [m/s]" is also somewhat dubious because if $v$ is a speed then that is what it is. It does not matter what units someone may be thinking about.

Now when it comes to plotting graphs of actual data, then if we want to be logical then we have a choice. We can either give the label $v$ and then on every tick-mark on the axis we should write the full quantity, "1 m/s, 2 m/s, 3 m/s" etc. Or on the label we can write "$v / ({\rm m s}^{-1})$ and then on the tick marks just numbers $1, 2, 3$. This is entirely logical because when you divide a speed $v$ by another speed (1 m/s) you do indeed get a dimensionless number. This is the way graphs in physics were plotted for a long time, and often they still are plotted this way. However, people began to find the division sign and the round brackets a little ugly or hard to read, so they wanted to write something like "$v$ [m/s]" as the label on the axis of a graph. What is going on now is that the square bracket is sending the message "I am not a mathematical formula in the standard conventions of mathematics and physics; I am a comment telling you that what is plotted here is not $v$ but rather $v$ divided by (1 m/s)"-or, as it is commonly expressed, "$v$ in units of m/s".

Answer (score 0):

First I must add that I am not a member of MIT (student or professor), so I can't tell you exactly how dimensional analysis is done there.

However, seeing $v ~ \frac{m}{s}$ or $v ~ \left[\frac{m}{s}\right]$ written in a text somewhere (these being your #3 and #4) is more than dubious, so I think only option #2 remains correct. So units are put always next to concrete numbers, not to abstract notation for the physical quantity.

Therefore we do not place square brackets when numerical values of physical quantities are written (so we always have in a text "a body of mass 1 Kg" or "the body moves with speed $15 \frac{m}{s}$), nor do we use numerical values or units when doing dimensional analysis:

So we write:

$$v^2 = v_0^2 + 2 a t ~ \left [L^2 T^{-2}\right]$$

More you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Mechanics).